# Is the functor distribution law for the `Alt` typeclass trivial?

Tags: haskell, functor, free-theorem

I was looking at the laws for [the `Alt` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.3.4/docs/Data-Functor-Alt.html), which looks like this:

```
class Functor f => Alt f
  where
  (<!>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
```

One of the laws goes like this:

```
<$> left-distributes over <!>:  f <$> (a <!> b) = (f <$> a) <!> (f <$> b)
```

More verbosely, this is:

```
fmap f $ (<!>) a b = (<!>) (fmap f a) (fmap f b)
```

Let's say we uncurry the `<!>` operation, i.e. that we suppose the class is written like this:

```
class Functor f => Alt f
  where
  alt :: (f a, f a) -> f a
```

We can write a combinator like this:

```hs
mapBoth :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a, f a) -> (f b, f b)
mapBoth f = bimap (fmap f) (fmap f)
```

This represents the composition of the `type Pair a = (a, a)` functor with a given functor `f`. So it is itself the morphism mapping of a functor.

The law in question can now be written (without changing its meaning) like this:

```hs
fmap f . alt = alt . mapBoth f
```

Note that the `mapBoth f` is simply applying `fmap f` to both of the arguments of `alt`, as in the original statement of the law.

This is akin to demanding that `alt` is a natural transformation from the functor `(f -, f -)` to the functor `f -`.

However, isn't it actually impossible for a function of `alt`'s type *not* to be a natural transformation? How would one write a "bad" implementation of `alt` that that typechecks, but would be rejected by the law?

Comment: Yup, that looks right -- this law is a naturality property, which is given for free by parametricity.

Comment: Well, it can fail by `fmap` itself being non-law-abiding, and so have this law fail but without `alt` being "at fault", so to speak.

Comment: @DanielWagner Sure, but we typically don't restate the laws of the superclass in the subclass, assuming that's all this law degenerates to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the law holds for free, by parametricity.

Even then, these laws still have value.

1. It allows people to be aware of them without being adepts of programming language theory.
2. You will want to have these laws around if you port these interfaces to languages with weaker type systems.
3. Until Haskell is actually given formal semantics, we technically don't know that those free theorems hold. By sufficiently high standards of formality, it's not enough to pretend that Haskell is a pure polymorphic lambda-calculus. So we might as well add and check these "free" laws just in case.

Comment: It is useful to be aware of them, but it can cause confusion to present this as a law on par with the associativity law (for example the reason I started looking at this was because a friend suggested this law is the reason a particular instance doesn't exist). The selective functors [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/selective-0.4/docs/Control-Selective.html) does this better IMO, in that it separately lists laws and the theorems that follow from them.

Answer (score 4):

While it isn't the consensus of the other answers and comments, this is **not** a natural property of "real-world" Haskell.

It is helpful to developers who write non-parametric code to know when they should add constraints to remain compatible with code which takes parametricity for granted.

## A badly-behaved example

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Badly a where
  End :: a -> Badly a
  Cons :: a -> Badly b -> Badly a

(<++>) :: Badly a -> Badly b -> Badly a
(End a)    <++> r = Cons a r
(Cons a l) <++> r = Cons a (l <++> r)

instance Functor Badly where
  fmap f (End a) = End (f a)
  fmap f (Cons a r) = Cons (f a) r

instance Alt f where
  (<!>) = (<++>)
```

Comment: Would you have an example of a "real world" implementation of `alt` that would be usefully rejected by the law?

Comment: That's a difficult question - I don't claim to have knowledge of all domains. Heterogeneous lists which are existential over the tail type, where `alt` is concatenation, would do it. But if an example doesn't obey the law, it probably wouldn't have an `Alt` instance in the first place - the point was more that the law itself is not actually trivial, because parametricity is not a default assumption.

Comment: Assuming you mean something like `data HetList a = forall b. Semigroup b => HetList { head :: a, tail :: b }`, my point is that this specific law is not violated by any implementation `alt :: (HetList a, HetList a) -> HetList a` that typechecks (without resorting to partiality), regardless of what other laws it might violate. You can change the existential `Semigroup` to whatever constraint you like, even some weird lawless one like `Default`.

Comment: I've added the code of what I meant to the answer - but it is a contrived example. As I say, I don't profess knowledge of all possible domains: whether or not a real-life, in-production, example exists is not something I can answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding an example. I don't quite understand the `(End a)    <++>   = Cons a r` case though.

Comment: Typo - fixed that. There should have been the `r` argument in there.

Comment: I don't think even this example manages to violate the law. Given two `Badly a`s, mapping a function over their heads and then appending them doesn't produce a different result from appending them and then mapping a function over the head of the resulting `Badly`. The appended `Badly` always takes the `a` value from the first of its arguments, and whether we fmap the function over it before or after we append the tails makes no difference to the result.

Comment: Nice. Here's an even simpler counterexample: `data BadPair a where BadPair :: a -> b -> BadPair a; f <$> BadPair a b = BadPair (f a) b; BadPair a b <!> BadPair a' b' = BadPair a a'`. But can you observe the law violation without invoking `seq`? If not, it seems like a fairly benign violation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, to be able to recover any information about the existential `b`, you'd have to add some constraints to it, which forces you to add the constraints to `<++>`, which makes `<!>` fail to typecheck. For example the only definition of `Eq` you can give the type while still being able to define `alt` is one which ignores the tail.

Comment: If you limit yourself to `Eq` for equality, there are much simpler violations, including parametric ones.

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel What I mean is you need `Cons :: c b => a -> Badly b -> Badly a` to involve `b` at all in any notion of equality (even if it's something like serializing to a string and then comparing the result). But the moment you do that it becomes impossible to use the resulting `<++> :: c b => Badly a -> Badly b -> Badly a` as `<!>`, which supplies no such constraint.

Comment: I understand that - but the law doesn't only hold in terms of the `Eq` instance for the type, because then there would be parametric violations of such a law. That you cannot define an `Eq` instance on `Badly` to evidence the law violation does not mean that it does not exist.

Comment: The `Eq` constraint here is just an example, I don't mean to imply I'm looking for the law to hold in terms of `Eq.==`. I'm saying that without any constraints on `b`, `Badly a` is observationally equivalent to `a`. With constraints that allow them to be distinguished, `alt` becomes unimplementable.

Comment: `BadPair a` is isomorphic to `(a, Natural)`, so I don't think this example actually demonstrates that the law can be broken. I do not know of an example which does.

Comment: @DanielWagner This answer seem to claim, in a nutshell, that existential types break parametricity. I think that might be an illusion for the reason you mentioned in your example, which can be formalized a bit. If we encode `x :: exists b. (a,b)` as usual with `x :: forall r. (forall b. (a,b) -> r) -> r`, the issue should be clearer. Indeed, to observe the "lack of parametricity" it looks like we would need a non-parametric `observer :: (forall b. (a,b) -> r)` to pass to `x`, which we can't really construct. This can be extended to `Badly` as well, AFAICS.